# How to store date string in Django model with MySQL?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a date as String s_date '07/20/2015'.
I need to store this date in Django model with MySQL.
How can I do that? 
Suppose I have model Project and a dateField startingdate

```
new_project = Project()
new_project.startingdate = s_date
```

or

```
date = deadline.split('/')
year = date[2]
month = date[0]
day = date[1]
new_project.starting = datetime.date(year, month, day)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) to parse date-strings:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('07/20/2015', '%m/%d/%Y')
datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 20, 0, 0)
```

If you want a `date` object, do this:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('07/20/2015', '%m/%d/%Y').date()
datetime.date(2015, 7, 20)
```